# How openui5/SAP Web IDE works and why the text doesn't appear when I open the project in my PC?

Tags: web, ide, sapui5

When i open the openui5 project in SAP Web IDE, the project appears with css style and with text "Title" from i18n,but when i download the project and open in my PC, the project doesn't have css style and no text ( blank page).
How openui5/SAP Web IDE works and why the  text doesn't appear when I open the project in my PC?

[image: project open in SAP Web IDE]

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of web sites , SAP open university and SCN blogs that will help you get started. For example

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-55585
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/99ac68a5b1c3416ab5c84c99fefa250d.html

Answer (score 0):

The "Title" should appear in the i18n.properties file, and the Fiori style is part of the UI5 controls.